# Ubuntu 14.04 can't boot after hard shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi, shutdown

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 from wubi application with Windows 7 as partition. I was using ubuntu for some time. After that it freezes for some time and I shut it down by long press on the power button. when I start ubuntu again it doesn't boot and it gives me

Minimal Bash-Line editing is supported. for the first word. TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions
grub->

but I can still sing windows. Can anyone help me to reboot it again or at least to restore my files from my home directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a Ubuntu folder inside Windows. Maybe you can use a USB stick with ubuntu to boot your system so you can see the files inside that folder. IMHO you should install ubuntu properlly because wubi is not a good solution.

See this link [Installation from USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Or you can try this: [How to restore the wubi ubuntu bootloader](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/)